# How do I change the color of the cell highlight in Calc 7.3?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

[image: highlight image]

I've looked around and changed some values in the Application Colors dialog but none of them seem to be changing that light green. I find it too light to distinguish against a light background. Ideally I'd like a medium yellow color for the whole cell -- or at least to try some colors and see what I like.

N**ote I do not want to change to a dark theme**. Dark backgrounds are harder to read for people with astigmatism.

Comment: I have astigmatism and I love dark themes :D

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Dark+backgrounds+are+harder+to+read+for+people+with+astigmatism -- especially https://www.boia.org/blog/dark-mode-can-improve-text-readability-but-not-for-everyone